# FT232 is not detected by Device Manager

Tags: ftdi

When I plug my new FTI32RL in to my laptop, it turns on but it is not showing up in the device manager, not even as another device.

There is no connection sound, no notification, just the light glowing on the FTI32RL.

Comment: it might be a fake one that will need additional drivers. Can you show us a pic of the IC?

Answer (score 2):

See here for a quick guide: https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/AN_396-FTDI-Drivers-Installation-Guide-for-Windows-10.pdf

If this does not help, please check if it is reachable via FT_Prog. Please download FT_Prog from https://ftdichip.com/utilities/ and test. If it works, continue with setting up the device as you require.

If it doesn't work, check your Board (I assume you got a cheap board from like amazon) - Any soldering issues here? Any broken leads or anything else suspicious?

If not: Don't waste your time - just buy a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments but I think this is a necessary addendum to @ElectronicsStudent's answer. His answer helped point me to the right direction, but it basically leaves the reader looking at FT-Prog.

I had a proper prototype board (not DIY, not inexpensive) that I knew was working. I could program the main chip through USB and the FT chip's JTAG capabilities. However, I knew from the board's reference manual and documentation that there should be an exposed serial port, which Windows would refuse to discover.

After seeing that FT-Prog was able to identify the FT2232 chip on my dev board, I took note of the properties it exposed. Because Windows' Device Manager does not implement a search function, I had to download USBDeview (see here: https://superuser.com/questions/1357119/find-device-by-hardware-id-in-device-manager). There, I searched for the serial number obtained through FT-Prog, and found my development board. I clicked "Uninstall Selected Devices", re-connected the board, and after a few moments a serial port appeared in Device Manager.

Your mileage may vary, as chances are that your FT chip could be fake, fried/dead, misused or wrongly connected or soldered, it could be a bad USB cable or port etc. My problem specifically turned out to be within Windows, not in hardware (thankfully).

Comment: User jcolvin on the digilent forums can also help with restoring the FT2232 functionality of Digilent's development boards. https://forum.digilent.com/topic/3123-how-to-restore-ft2232-eeprom-back-to-factory-settings/ If this happens to be the reader's problem, then the solution is in replying to that thread.